# JavaScript function in onclick attribute does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a table in HTML that contains a button to show more details. By clicking on a certain cell the div opens and shows more information. That works perfectly (even though I used the onclick attr).
The div contains a button that calls the folowing function and closes the div:

```js
function hideDescription() {
  console.log("Hallo");
  var allDescriptions = document.getElementsByClassName('description_container');

  for (var i = 0; i < allDescriptions.length; i++) {
    allDescriptions[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = "auto";
}

function showDescription(element) {
  var allDescriptions = document.getElementsByClassName('description_container');

  for (var i = 0; i < allDescriptions.length; i++) {
    allDescriptions[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  elem = document.querySelector('#' + element);
  elem.style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = "hidden";
}
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}

#spells_table {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#spells_table td, #spells_table th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#spells_table td:last-child {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#spells_table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#spells_table tr:hover {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

#spells_table th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #007BFF;
    color: white;
}

.description_container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0005;
    width: 100vW;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.nopadding {
    padding: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<table id="spells_table">
  <tr>
    <td>Some Content</td>
    <td>Some Content</td>
    <td>Some Content</td>
    <td>Some Content</td>
    <td>Some Content</td>
    <td>Some Content</td>
    <td>Some Content</td>
    <td>Some Content</td>
    <td onclick="showDescription('element_1')">
    Some Descritption
      <div class="description_container" id="element_1" style="display: none;">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet
        <button onclick="hideDescription()">close</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It doesn´t work not matter whether I place it before or after the table.
The weird thing is that at least the "Hallo" appears in the console. That means that the function gets called. But the div doesnt disapear allthough it works if I call the function from the console.
Why does it not work? There are no errors.

Comment: Nobody can help you without seeing table. Create [mre] by pressing <> button in editor so we can see for ourselves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It’s possible that this closes it but it immediately reopens because the event bubbles up to the container’s onclick.

Try stopping the event from propagating:

```js
function hideDescription(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // ...the rest of your function
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you